# MySQL Temporary Table query - add calculated column to table calculated in select

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to make a temporary table from a query with another column which is calculated in the query...

Here is my query:

```
asprintf(&query,
"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task_tab (PRIMARY KEY(event_id))"
"SELECT V.id as event_id, V.event_time, D.user, V.location FROM device D "
"JOIN device_service DS ON D.id = DS.device_id "
"JOIN services S ON DS.service_id = S.id "
"JOIN device_event V ON D.id = V.device_id "
"WHERE V.store = 'event_box' AND S.options = 'box_length' AND (S.flags & 1 = 1)"
"AND V.event_time + (IF(S.value IS NULL, %d, S.value) * 86400000) <= %llu"
"AND D.id IN ( SELECT D.id FROM device D "
    "JOIN device_service DS ON D.id = DS.device_id "
    "JOIN services S ON DS.service_id = S.id "
    "WHERE S.action = 'delete' AND (S.flags & 1 = 1)",
app_config->def_expire, current_epoch_ms);
```

I'd like to create a column 'expire_time' in this temporary table, and store the result of this part of the query in that column:

```
V.event_time + (IF(S.value IS NULL, %d, S.value) * 86400000)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
V.event_time + (IF(S.value IS NULL, %d, S.value) * 86400000) AS `expire_time`
```

to your SELECT filed list